# jQuery - how to get external image size

Tags: jquery

I'm generating a list of the img tags in the loop:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
   <img class='my-mimg' alt='' src='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=someDynamicID'  style='max-width : 700px; max-height : 700px;' />
}
```

I don't know the size of that images, and I want to get the size of the first image:

```
$('img.my-mimg:eq(0)').css('width');
$('img.my-mimg:eq(0)').css('height')
```

but I get 0 value. How then to get that size ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait until the image is loaded before you can get it's size

```
$('img.my-mimg:eq(0)').on('load', function() {
    var width = $(this).css('width');
}).each(function() {
    if (this.complete) $(this).load(); // Fixes caching issues in IE
});
```